# Best Practice for Storyboarding Startup Checks

Tags: ios, xcode

My app needs to perform a number of checks each time it starts. For example:

Have we captured the users's details.
Has the user added any topics to his/her list.
Is the user in the middle of editing a topic.

Each one of these requires a scene to allow the details to be entered. So I could set up the storyboard to enter the first scene and if that is not required programatically move to the second scene to see if that is required.
Or I could set up a dummy first screen (and launchscreen) to display a logo while it programatically decides which scene to jump to.

Cycling through the screens would seem to be the way xcode would like me to do it, but the other way seems more efficient.

Comment: I've done similar things with login screens where I load the login view modally if I see that the user is not logged in when the app starts. I prefer not use the segue in the story board for this however as it becomes a mess very quickly if you have multiple different segues going in and out of views.

Comment: "As you can probably tell I am completely new to swift" No, because this question has nothing to do with Swift. It's about Cocoa Touch. There's no language relevance in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time `application:didFinishLaunching:` is called, your storyboard's initial view controller has already been assigned to your window's `rootViewController`. If that's not what you want — because you discover, in your checks, that the user has done one of the required stages already — then just reach right into your storyboard and grab a later view controller (using its storyboard id, by calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`) and make *it* the `rootViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you translate "reach right into your storyboard" into a little code?

Comment: Consult the UIStoryboard documentation, under `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.